# Передать подарок из корзины в заказ Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

есть условие, если сумма товара больше 1100, добавляем к товару подарок, подарок выводится но как его передать дальше в заказ?

```
<?php
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $cart_total_prod1 = 1100;
        $cart_total_prod2 = 1500;
        $cart_total_prod3 = 2000;

        if( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total_prod1 && $woocommerce->cart->total <= $cart_total_prod2) {
            echo "подарок 1";

        }

        if( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total_prod2 && $woocommerce->cart->total <= $cart_total_prod3) {
            echo "подарок 2";

        }
        if( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total_prod3) {
            echo "подарок 3";

        }
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

На хук `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`, сохраняете подарок в заказ:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_gift' );
function add_gift( $order_id ) {
    $order = new \WC_Order( $order_id );
    if ( $order->get_total() > 1100 ) {
        $order->->update_meta_data( '_gift', 'Gift 1' ); 
    }
    // ...
}
```

На хук `woocommerce_admin_order_items_after_line_items` или любой, который вам нравится выводите данные:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_items_after_line_items', 'show_gift_in_admin' );
function show_gift_in_admin( $order_id ) {
    $order = new \WC_Order( $order_id );
    $gift = $order->get_meta( '_gift' );
    if ( ! $gift ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><?php echo $gift; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```